# How to use Bing Spatial service to get nearby areas and how to add them to our map control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps, httpwebresponse

I am using query Api to get the near by locations with in given radius. How to add them to our map control and bind them to a UI control.

```
 public class SpatialDataQuerying
{
   static void Main()
   {
   SpatialDataQuerying queryTest = new SpatialDataQuerying();
   queryTest.RunExampleQueries();      
   }

   public void RunExampleQueries()
   {
      ExampleFindByAreaRadius();   
   }
   public async void ExampleFindByAreaRadius()
     {
      string dataSourceName = "petrolbunk";
      string dataEntityName = "petrolbunk";

      string accessId = DataSourceID;

      string bingMapsKey = BingMapsKey;

      double SearchLatitude = 47.63674;
      double SearchLongitude =  - 122.30413;

      double Radius = 3;      
      string requestUrl = string.Format("http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/{0}/{1}/{2}" + "?spatialFilter=nearby({3},{4},{5})&key={6}",accessId,dataSourceName,
    dataEntityName,SearchLatitude, SearchLongitude, Radius, bingMapsKey);
```

As you know after this query the url is sent through HTTP web request.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Now how to store this response to a list and display them in map control. Also how to bind the area to our UI control.

Comment: I think your question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212447/how-to-get-nearby-locations-using-query-api-in-windows-phone-8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its already a duplicate of another question. Try his code and check weather it works.

```
internal class NAVTEQEUDataSource : INAVTEQEUDataSource
{
public async Task<IList<Geopoint>> SearchNearBy(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, int entityTypeId, int maxResult, string bingMapKey)
{
    const string spatialBaseUrl = "http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/";
    string url =
        "c2ae584bbccc4916a0acf75d1e6947b4/NavteqEU/NavteqPOIs?spatialFilter=nearby({0},{1},{2})&$filter=EntityTypeID%20eq%20'{3}'&$select=EntityID,DisplayName,Latitude,Longitude,__Distance&$top={4}&key={5}";
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(spatialBaseUrl) };
    url = string.Format(url, latitude, longitude, radius, entityTypeId, maxResult, bingMapKey);
    string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    XmlUtil xmlUtil = new XmlUtil(response);
    IList<XElement> properties = xmlUtil.GetElements("entry").ToList();
    IList<Geopoint> result = new List<Geopoint>();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        BasicGeoposition basicGeoposition = new BasicGeoposition();

        double temp;
        if (double.TryParse(xmlUtil.GetRelativeElement(property, "content.properties.Latitude").Value, out temp))
            basicGeoposition.Latitude = temp;
        if (double.TryParse(xmlUtil.GetRelativeElement(property, "content.properties.Longitude").Value, out temp))
            basicGeoposition.Longitude = temp;
        result.Add(new Geopoint(basicGeoposition));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: With some changes I got the output.. Thanks for your contribution